# Running xpath queries on multiple xml documents in asp.net mvc3 with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, xpath, entity-framework-4

My supervisor is under the impression that it is possible to run queries on a MySql database that run xPath queries on the xml documents stored.

The table I am concerned with is called Responses and has the following columns

```
    UserId, UploadTime, RawXml
```

I already get all the responses for a particular user by

```
     public ActionResult UserResponses(Guid userid)
     {
        var allResponses = ZodiacData.Responses;
        var userResponses = (from r in allResponses
                        where r.UserId == userid
                        select r)
        //...populate model here....
         return PartialView("_responseTable", responsesmodel)
     }
```

However now I am trying to get all the responses to a specific questionnaire which is referenced in the root node of the RawXml (by qid and qver, please see the example below)
The root node:

```
     <response qid="5" qver="3" date="..-..-.." qname="full">
```

Does anyone know how I can do that in asp.net, what should I add to the query in the function above? any help would be great, even if just a pointer to the right kind of articles online.
Thank you!

Comment: why dont you do as your code shows, but deserialize the xml into a model and then run linq queries on that?  much less complicated and more maintainable is the data structore or criteria changes

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to run XPath queries on XML data in database but you cannot use EF for that because EF doesn't support that. If you want to use XPath in database queries you must write your SQL directly.

.NET 4.5 should change this little bit because you would be able to map table valued SQL function and hide that XPath query inside that function.

Comment: Hey @Ladislav, do you know a good tutorial/example of how I would write my SQL directly? Does it mean I need to disregard Entity Framework altogether?

Comment: No I don't know about the tutorial for MySQL - use Google. You don't need to disregard EF - you just need to execute queries with XPath conditions through SQL. You can still use EF's infrastructure to execute SQL - for example [`ExecuteStoreQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx).